# I'm stumped at looping through a returned list of URLs

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My first python project, I'm trying to scrape restaurant inspection. One site has summaries that offer keys to the detailed reports that I want to scrape. I'm stumped at looping through the keyed list of urls to get the details.

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import datetime
import re
import lxml
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

try:
    insp = pd.read_csv("ftp://dbprftp.state.fl.us/pub/llweb/5fdinspi.csv", 
                       usecols=[2,14,18,80,81])
except IOError:
    print("The file is not accessible.")
insp.columns = ["CountyName", "InspectDate", 
                "NumHighVio", "LicenseID", "VisitID"]
# filter for alachua county restaurants
alachua = insp[insp.CountyName == 'Alachua']
# filter for restaurants that had at least one serious violation
alachua = alachua[alachua.NumHighVio > 0]
# change date string to date object
alachua['InspectDate'] = pd.to_datetime(alachua['InspectDate'])
# sort most recent
alachua = alachua.sort_values('InspectDate', ascending=False)
# prefer to have user set timedelta below:
today = pd.to_datetime('today')
startDay = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
alachua = alachua[(alachua['InspectDate'] > startDay) & 
    (alachua['InspectDate'] < today)]
# takes LicenseID and VisitID, passes it into the urls for detailed reports
for index, rows in alachua.iterrows():
    visitID = rows['VisitID']
    licID = rows['LicenseID']
    urls = "https://www.myfloridalicense.com/inspectionDetail.asp?InspVisitID= 
        %s &licid= %s" % (visitID, licID)
    urls = urls.replace(' ', '')
    print(urls)
## here's my problem:
for url in urls:
    def get_inspect_detail():   
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
        details = soup.find_all('font', {'face':'verdana'})[10:]

        for detail in details:
            siteName = details[0].text
            licNum = details[2].text
            siteRank = details[4].text
            expDate = details[6].text
            primeStatus = details[8].text
            secStatus = details[10].text
            siteAddress = details[12].text
            inspectResult = details[20].text
            observed1 = details[34].get_text
            observed2 = details[36].text
            observed3 = details[38].text
            observed4 = details[40].text
            observed5 = details[42].text
            observed6 = details[44].text
            observed7 = details[46].text
            observed8 = details[48].text
            observed9 = details[50].text
            observed10 = details[52].text

            detailsLib = {
                'Restaurant': siteName,
                'License': licNum,
                'Rank': siteRank,
                'Expires': expDate,
                'Primary': primeStatus,
                'Secondary': secStatus,
                'Address': siteAddress,
                'Result': inspectResult,
                'Observed1': observed1,
                'Observed2': observed2,
                'Observed3': observed3,
                'Observed4': observed4,
                'Observed5': observed5,
                'Observed6': observed6,
                'Observed7': observed7,
                'Observed8': observed8,
                'Observed9': observed9,
                'Observed10': observed10                  
                }
repr(get_inspect_detail())
```

Probably an obvious mistake or lack of knowledge, but I can get the unscrubbed data for one url, but not for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see a reason to define your function inside the loop. You would end up with a lot of redundant definitions this way. Second, you could just define a result list and accumulate the detailsLib objects inside it.

```
def get_inspect_detail(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    details = soup.find_all('font', {'face': 'verdana'})[10:]
    result = []
    for detail in details:
        siteName = details[0].text
        licNum = details[2].text
        siteRank = details[4].text
        expDate = details[6].text
        primeStatus = details[8].text
        secStatus = details[10].text
        siteAddress = details[12].text
        inspectResult = details[20].text
        observed1 = details[34].get_text
        observed2 = details[36].text
        observed3 = details[38].text
        observed4 = details[40].text
        observed5 = details[42].text
        observed6 = details[44].text
        observed7 = details[46].text
        observed8 = details[48].text
        observed9 = details[50].text
        observed10 = details[52].text

        detailsLib = {
            'Restaurant': siteName,
            'License': licNum,
            'Rank': siteRank,
            'Expires': expDate,
            'Primary': primeStatus,
            'Secondary': secStatus,
            'Address': siteAddress,
            'Result': inspectResult,
            'Observed1': observed1,
            'Observed2': observed2,
            'Observed3': observed3,
            'Observed4': observed4,
            'Observed5': observed5,
            'Observed6': observed6,
            'Observed7': observed7,
            'Observed8': observed8,
            'Observed9': observed9,
            'Observed10': observed10
        }
        result.append(detailsLib)

    return result


for url in urls:
    repr(get_inspect_detail(url))
```

Comment: Loop is set inside the function now. Maybe better to separate the two: define the function and then call it in the loop?

Comment: Thats what you would do if you want to define once, use everywhere. But not only that, you said you get the true answer for the last one instance only right?

Well thats not what happens actually. You get the answer for each url but you do not accumulate them anywhere, thats why your result contains only one set of details. This is where the `result.append` comes in

Comment: Yes, after I put the urls into a list before passing them through the function. Thanks!

Comment: @DRay Glad to help! Good start as a first project!